# Access to class member within closure

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a class method and a closure within this method. How I can access to class member from closure?

```
Person = function(x) {
  this.x = x;
}

Person.prototype = {
   myMethod: function() {
      $('#myBtn').click( function() {
         // how to access to this.x? the this reference points in another context 
      });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use of [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) will help you here

```
Person = function(x) {
  this.x = x;
}

Person.prototype.myMethod = function() {
  $('#myBtn').click(function() {
    this.x;
  }.bind(this));
};
```

---

You can use some better separation of code here too

```
Person = function(x) {
  this.x = x;
};

Person.prototype.myMethod = function {
  $('#myBtn').click(this.clickHandler.bind(this));
};

Person.prototype.clickHandler = function(event) {
  console.log(this.x);
};
```

**Note** if you want to support older browsers, check out [es5-shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim)

---

**EDIT**

I'm revisiting this after ~6 months and I would probably write the above code differently. I like the private/public exposure here. Also, no need for any fanciful binds or anything like that **^.^**

```
function Person(x, $button) {

  // private api
  function onClick(event) {
    console.log(x);
  }

  function myMethod() {
    $button.click();
  }

  // exports
  this.x        = x;
  this.myMethod = myMethod;

  // init
  $button.click(onClick);
}

var b = $("#myBtn"),
    p = new Person("foo", b);

p.x;          // "foo"
p.myMethod(); // "foo"
btn.click();  // "foo"
```

Comment: I think it's important to note here that `bind()` here is referring to ES5's `Function.prototype.bind()` and not `JQuery.bind()`

Comment: @WillM, the docs I linked are the MDN JavaScript docs; not the jQuery API. This should be pretty obvious if the OP actually cares to dig in further. Nevertheless, I updated the link text.

Answer (score 2):

Just assign `this` to some other variable, for example `_this`:

```
Person = function(x) {
    this.x = x;
}

Person.prototype = {
    myMethod: function() {
        var _this = this;
        $('#myBtn').click( function() {
            console.log(_this.x);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Person = function(x) {
  this.x = x;
}

Person.prototype = {
   myMethod: function() {
      var self = this;
      $('#myBtn').click( function() {
         // Access to self.x 
      });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A proxy would be very useful here.

Right now, you're assigning an anonymous function to the click event. By default the context will be the event's and separate from your object.

With a proxy you can assign a particular context to a (callback) function. Thus, when the event fires, you're dealing with your person object.

1. Assign the event handler in a separate function like `initialize()`, and have `myMethod()` be the handler.
2. Use a `JQuery.proxy()` to assign the object`s context to the event handler.

   ```
   Person.prototype = {
       initialize: function() {
           $('#myBtn').click($.proxy(this.myMethod, this));
       },

       myMethod: function(event) {
        ...
        console.log(this); // Person object
       }
   }
   ```

---

Just to elicit the difference between my and @naomik's solution:

- `JQuery.proxy()` is a temporary or narrow assignment to a context.
- `Function.prototype.bind()` is a strong context assignment. The method will be "forever" bound to the context you give it.